# How to generate unique id in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, uniqueidentifier

I am new to react native and working on my first project in expo. I am trying to generate unique id for every order that is being placed by the user, below is what I have tried

```
 const orderId = () => {
    var S4 = () => {
      return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    };
    return (
      S4() +
      S4() +
      "-" +
      S4() +
      "-" +
      S4() +
      "-" +
      S4() +
      "-" +
      S4() +
      S4() +
      S4()
    );
  };
  console.log(orderId);
```

what I am getting in terminal is
[Function orderId]

Comment: if you can use libraries, try this one -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-uuid
totally helpful, easy to use and light

Comment: Hey thanks for responding .. tried it and it worked. thanks!

Comment: Please check this https://jsbin.com/kiyunabesu/edit?js,console

Comment: The real problem you had was calling the function reference `orderID` rather than executing the function `orderID()`. You can simply change the last line to execute the function and your algorithm will generate UUID's.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the following:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-uuid

`npm install react-native-uuid`

```
import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';
uuid.v4(); // ⇨ '11edc52b-2918-4d71-9058-f7285e29d894'
```

If you are not able to use other libraries in your project see the following related question:
[How to create a GUID / UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid)

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this problem today....tried to use nanoid in React Native and Baaam...
Well then...So why not write our own simple solution? This one does the job just fine :)

```
export function generateUUID(digits) {
    let str = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXZ';
    let uuid = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < digits; i++) {
        uuid.push(str[Math.floor(Math.random() * str.length)]);
    }
    return uuid.join('');
}
```

```
generateUUID(10) // 7ABLSma6F6
generateUUID(32) // FCGQ91Q5r2y3PkkPFuHhFh9JusMMDFwR
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function guidGenerator(){
    vary S4 = function(){
        return (((1+Math.random())*0x10000)|0).to String(16).substring(1);
    };
    return (S4()+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+"-"+S4()+S4()+S4());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your code question rather than suggesting an alternative library -

The only problem you had was logging the function object reference `orderID` rather than executing the function `orderID()`. This is why the console output was [Function orderId].

You can simply change the last line to execute the function and your algorithm will generate UUID's.

```
const orderId = () => {

  const S4 = () => {
    return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);
  };

  return (
    S4() +
    S4() +
    "-" +
    S4() +
    "-" +
    S4() +
    "-" +
    S4() +
    "-" +
    S4() +
    S4() +
    S4()
  );
}

console.log(orderId());

// output: "87dae617-994c-c506-3a43-da55ec0586e4"
```

Answer (score 0):

## 2023-02: Expo SDK 48 update

You can now use `expo-crypto` to generate `uuid` v4:

```js
import * as Crypto from "expo-crypto";

const UUID = Crypto.randomUUID();
```

More info in the [official documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/crypto/#cryptorandomuuid).

Comment: expo-crypto seems kind of broken right now. https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/24021

Answer (score -1):

You can use urid package `npm install urid`

```
import urid from 'urid';

urid(); // qRpky22nKJ4vkbFZ
```

Read full docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/urid